# AtmosphereHandler is guaranteed to preserve the instance?

Tags: jakarta-ee, glassfish, websocket, ejb, atmosphere

I'm using AtmosphereFramework's WebSockets, i've got a class annotated like this:

```
@WebSocketHandlerService(path = "/gts")
public class GameSocket extends WebSocketHandlerAdapter {

@Override void onOpen(WebSocket webSocket) {...}
@Override void onTextMessage(WebSocket webSocket, String message) throws IOException {...}
```

And i'd like to know if all calls (onOpen, onTextMessage, ...) from a SINGLE socket connection are guaranteed to use one and only one instance of GameSocket.

Else, i'm searching a way to keep user sessions into this JavaEE/Glassfish/EJB3 Websocket only environment.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

(1) Yes, only one instance

(2) There are some known issue with Session and GlassFish. Try it and if you see some issue, just come to the [mailing list](https://groups.google.com/group/atmosphere-framework?pli=1) and I will describe how you can use the `AtmosphereConfig.properties()` to store state.

(I am Atmosphere's creator).